# Google PageSpeed кеширование сторонних JS скриптов

Tags: apache, кэширование, pagespeed-insights

Здравствуйте.
Google PageSpeed рекомендует кешировать скрипты

```
http://connect.facebook.net/az_AZ/sdk.js (20 минут)
http://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render (30 минут)
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js (30 минут)
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (60 минут)
https://oauth.googleusercontent.com/…e:rpc:shindig.random:shindig.sha1.js?c=2 (60 минут)
https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/osd.js (60 минут)
http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 часа)
```

Они располагаются на сторонних серверах. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего делать не надо. Сами сервера отдают эти файлы с указанием времени кэширования. Пример:

[image: http://connect.facebook.net/az_AZ/sdk.js]
[image: http://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=render]

Comment: Да, вот это я тоже видел, однако google уж очень настоятельно рекомендовал сделать это. Мне показалось странным то, что среди скриптов почти все скрипты как раз таки ему принадлежат.