# Как уменьшить время загрузки страницы на которые влияют посторонние библиотеки?

Tags: ссылки, оптимизация-сайтов, долгая-загрузка

Есть сайт где используются много сторонних Javascript библиотек.Это библиотеки `facebook`, `google` и т п.

Пользуюсь отчетами об эффективности от сайтa https://gtmetrix.com/

Где сказано что надо оптимизировать эти внешние библиотеки путем добавления `expiration date` [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

**Мысли вслух:**

Я могу добавлять поля заголовков только в ответ на запросы, поступающие на мой собственный сервер. Если запрос отправляется на другой сервер, скажем сервер Google, то это сервер Google, который отвечает на запрос.

Поэтому единственным решением моей проблемы является размещение внешних ресурсов на моём собственном сервере. Но это возможно только в том случае, если эти ресурсы являются статическими, не меняются от запроса к запросу и не зависят от других вещей.

Думаю все коды слить в один файл и подгружать только его вместо всех их.Написать какой нибудь `Watcher` который проверял бы не изменилось ли что в этих библиотеках и при необходимости который обновит существующий.

**Вопрос :**

Как уменьшить время загрузки страницы путем оптимизации внешних библиотек?

Comment: Не используйте внешние библиотеки :) Или оставьте все как есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444656/186083

Comment: @visman Зря вы так .Этот вопрос как головная боль у многих,и многие бы захотели получить ответ на нeго

Comment: @Sergey, гугл указывает время кеширования файлов. Фейсбук вероятно тоже. Кто виноват, что "отчеты об эффективности" программируют так криво?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, если впрямую.

Как вы правильно заметили, время кеширования внешних ресурсов ваш сервер установить не может. Все, что вы можете сделать - разместить эти внешние js и css у себя на сервере и обновлять их по cron.

Всяким рекомендациям типа gmetrix или pagespeed ваш сайт станет соответствовать. Вот только Google сам себе противоречит, требуя в pagespeed кеширования всех ресурсов не менее недели и кешируя свои скрипты (например, карты) на 2 часа.

Практического смысла в натягивании оценок по внешним библиотекам - ноль, кроме удовлетворения требованиям заказчика, который молится на pagespeed или gmetrix, как на икону.

Comment: Да точно :) честно говоря я об этих систем даже и не слышал пока непотребовали оглядываться на них